# Entity Framework - joining multiple record to one record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have one table that name is A that is master, another table that name is B is detail

In A and B I have below records:

A table:

```
Id    Name         Family
-------------------------
 1   Ebrahim      Golkhani
 2   Javad        Nasiri
```

in B table:

```
AId    FactorName       Value
------------------------
 1     BaseSalary       1000
 1     Tax              10
 1     Insurance        20
 2     BaseSalary       2000
 2     Tax              50
 2     Insurance        30
```

I want to retrieve data like this:

```
Name     Family     BaseSalary    Tax     Insurance ....
--------------------------------------------------------
Ebrahim  Golkhani   1000          10      20
Javad    Nasiri     2000          50      30
```

record in table b is dynamic, this means that factor name is not static.

I want to implement this in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableA.Join(TableB,x=>x.Aid,y=>y.Aid, (x,y) => new { name = x.name,family = x.family,
                        BaseSalary = y.Where(x.FactorName=="BaseSalary").First().Value,
                        Tax = y.Where(x.FactorName=="Tax").First().Value,
                        Insurance = y.Where(x.FactorName=="Insurance").First().Value
                        //.....
    }).ToList()
```

Comment: TableB.Where(y=>y.Aid = x.Aid).BaseSalary can't be . because my column name is FactorName and in model i have FactorName

Comment: @EbrahimGolkhani : check now.

Comment: Ok, but i have dynamic records , BaseSalary =... where BaseSalary is dynamic record name.

Comment: @EbrahimGolkhani : that may not be possible with linq. your requirements need building property names at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var results  =  from g in tab2.GroupBy(k => k.AId)
                join t1 in tab1 on g.Key equals t1.Id
                select new
                {
                    t1.Name,
                    t1.Family,
                    BaseSalary = g.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.FactorName.Equals("BaseSalary")).Value, 
                    Insurance = g.SingleOrDefault(c => c.FactorName.Equals("Insurance")).Value,
                    Tax = g.SingleOrDefault(c => c.FactorName.Equals("Tax")).Value,
                };
```

*Please note*, this is not validating nulls in your table, I'm leaving it to you to add those validations

Working [Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rANtXS) attached.

Comment: @EbrahimGolkhani  : does this not solved your problem? or are you looking for something else?